Convert svg to png in Python using Inkscape, but nothing works
I want to loop through a folder, take all SVGs and convert them to PNGs, then use OCR to read text from the images.
I know the OCR part of my code works, because I did read text successfully from PNGs. But somehow I can't for the life of me figure out how to first convert all SVGs to PNGs, and then do the OCR parts. So that's where my code gets stuck, in the conversion.
I have tried everything I possibly can but get stuck in malfunctioning library hell.
These are NOT working for me:

cairosvg
svglib / reportlab
Inkscape command line
pyvips
Image Magick

I am still trying to get the Inkscape command to work. I tried changing the Inkscape path from .exe to .com, but no difference there.
And now I run my code but nothing happens. I'm testing using a single svg file in a single folder. But now I can't even use breakpoints, the code won't stop at the break point. As you can see none of the print statements print, only the one at the end, outside of the loop. I've tried closing and reopening Visual Studio Code, but nothing. Please help.
import cv2
import glob
import pytesseract
import subprocess
#import time

# Path to tesseract.exe
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'

#Path to Inkscape
inkscape_path = 'C:/Program Files/Inkscape/bin/inkscape.exe'

pva_image_list = []
#start_time = time.time()

# Get a list of image file paths from a folder, including subfolders (**)
for img_name in glob.glob('my-images/**/*.svg', recursive=True):
  print('Svg path name:', img_name)
  try:
      png_converted = subprocess.run([inkscape_path, '--export-type=png', f'--export-filename=file.png', img_name])
      print('png_converted: ', type(png_converted.stdout))
      # Reads the image
      img = cv2.imread(png_converted)
      print(img)

      # Find text on each image, returns string of text
      text = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)

      # Search for keywords in extracted text. No match returns a -1.
      if text.find('text to read') > -1 or text.find('more text') > -1:
        # Add filename of image to list if there's a match
        pva_image_list.append(img_name)
  except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass

# Print to console. You can select each list item in the console to open image in VSC.
print(pva_image_list)

The output of this code:
PS C:\Users\v-wiazure\Desktop> python test-svg-convert.py                                                                                                          
[]
PS C:\Users\v-wiazure\Desktop> 


As far as subprocess.run goes, your code is working fine. I have commented out the tesseract and cv2 lines for testing. Print statements are working fine for svg files as well. I suggest you try to isolate the problem and move on from there.

Thanks @BcK for confirming. I just realized the .svg image was changed into a .png image, but then it was not a "real" png, cuz I tried to open it and my photo viewer said "It looks like we don't support this file type". So that makes sense why nothing was added to the list, the code couldn't read the image anymore. And once I ran the code, any future runs would give blank results, since it's now a png file.

I'm not sure what to do now. I also tried so many different OCR libraries. If only pytesseract could read svgs, I would have no problems. But I couldn't get any of those other OCR libs to work either.
